# Unif affine function for RV U Unif distributed

Tags: probability, statistics, functions, random-variables

Let $U$ be a uniform random variable in $[0, 1]$ and let $a < b$ be two real numbers.
I wish to find an affine function $h$ such that the random variable $V = h(U)$ has a uniform distribution in $[a, b]$.

Would $h(U) = U + \frac{b}{a}$ be a solution?

How would you verify this?

Comment: Your title is deliciously cryptic.

Comment: @JeanMarie :D Sorry!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, that function doesn't fill the bill. The function $h(u) = (b-a)u + a$ will do. Indeed, let $X = h(U)$ and note that $h$ is bijective, with inverse $h^{-1}(x) = \frac{x-a}{b-a}$. Thus, we can derive the distribution of $X$ by applying the change-of-variable argument to $U$, i.e.

\begin{align*}
f_X(x) &= f_U(h^{-1}(x)) \frac{\text{d}h^{-1}(x)}{\text{d}x}\\
& = f_U\left(\frac{x-a}{b-a}\right)\frac{1}{b-a}\\ 
& = \frac{1}{b-a}1_{(a,b)}(x),
\end{align*}

where $1_{(a,b)}(x)$ is an indicator function that takes value 1 if $x\in(a,b)$ and takes value 0 otherwise.

Comment: I am sorry, but your notations are not clear to me. What does $1_{(a,b)}$ mean?

Comment: If you could start from "then" and elaborate more on what you did, it would be appreciated. I want to understand the reason why you had that function, and the way you proved is not clear to me. Though I see how the CDF played a role.

Comment: Hi @user1125632, my intention was to give you hint and leave the rest to you. I'll expand my answer. By the way, $1_{(a,b)}(x)$ is a standard notation for the indicator function in the set $(a,b)$.

Comment: I haven't seen indicator function yet

Comment: @user1125632 about "why I had that function": just intuition.

Comment: Well, if you see it, it's actually the CDF of $U[a;b]$. I mean $\frac{x-a}{b-a}$ as the CDF

Comment: I didn't start from that, but yes it's the CDF of $X$ (in my notation).

Comment: Then you're a true mathematician!

Comment: @user1125632 You've forgotten to accept the answer.

Comment: Actually, it s strange you didn't know/use the idea of inverse CDF method to derive a distribution from the other, and somewhat came with that function, unless you used only analysis idea

Comment: @user1125632 Invoking the inverse CDF method would have been another path, but then I would have to explain it. Since, in my experience, this is presumably a homework or self-study question, I can only give hits leaving the "meat" to you. Best.